# Ajax get request laravel 5.4 resource controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've been searching for similar question in a while but I couldn't find what would actually help my issue.

Using Laravel 5.4.

So I have a resource controller and its index method that returns a view with some data attached to it.
Then I want to make an ajax request from the view returned which is a search request.

```
e.preventDefault();
        let q = $('#inputserver').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/servers",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'data': q},
            success: function(response){
                console.log('Successo');
            }
        })
```

That, for how a resource controller's methods are structured should invoke the index method, in which I want to identify if I have an Ajax request incoming.
If I do, I'll search with a query in an Eloquent Model for the data retrieved by the search form and of course I want to show only the matching results.

This is my controller code:

```
if(!$request->ajax()){
        $colonna = 'id';
        $servers = Server::orderBy($colonna, 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('servers.index', array('servers' => $servers));
    }
    else{
        $servers= Server::where('name', '=', $request->data)->paginate(10);
        return view('servers.index', array('servers' => $servers));
    }
```

The issue is that nothing is happening, so the ajax request isn't even considered, can someone help me with this? I'm almost sure the issue is some obvious things I forgot or didn't consider.
Thank you in advance, I'll edit if you would need some more info about it.

**EDIT:**

This is the route I have `Route::resource('servers', 'ServerController');`

**EDIT2:**

I'm sorry *ids* are in Italian, but I of course select them correctly when using jQuery.

```
<div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span>
             <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </span>
     </div>
     {{Form::text('search', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'inputserver' , 'placeholder' => 'Cerca..'))}}
     <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="cercaserver">Go!</button>
    </span>
```

Comment: Edited showing it!

Comment: strange. Can you add the blade with ajax aswell, and make sure jquery is being loaded aswell

Comment: Sorry it took some time to indent that correctly :/

Answer (score 0):

The blade file is messy.Try to create a form open and form close and make the button submit of type. And try to change your ajax to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cercaserver').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = $('#inputserver').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: './servers',
            data: {input: input},

        });
    });
});
```

make sure you are loading jquery.

Comment: Tried it, but still not working, in the controller it's not even entering the else statement which is where I want it to go if it's a ajax request. Am I doing that right?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by nothing's happening? What was shown in the console when the ajax request was fired?

Also, you're returning a view, you might want to return a json array of your results?

`return $servers;`

Laravel will automagically convert it into a JSON response

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#creating-responses

Or if you want to be specific:

`return response()->json($servers);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses

Edit:
I think I already know the problem, in your resource controller function `index`, is there a parameter called `$request`? It might be non existing and for sure will throw a 500 internal server error because you used it in your condition.